# Как можно повернуть pygame картинку?

Tags: python, изображения, pygame

хотелось бы узнать о способах поворота изображений в pygame. Желательно на следующем коде:

```
import pygame as pg
import pygame


WIDTH = 850
HEIGHT = 500
FPS = 60
x = 455
y = 367
# Задаем цвета
FILL = ("#dfbd15")

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("AI car")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
track = pygame.image.load('трасса.png').convert_alpha()
car = pygame.image.load('car.png').convert_alpha()
screen.fill(FILL)
screen.blit(track, (0, 0))
screen.blit(car, (x, y))

# Цикл игры
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:   
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
               #поворот car направо
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                #поворот car налево
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
                x -=1                                              
                screen.fill((FILL)) 
                screen.blit(track, (0, 0))       
                screen.blit(car,(x,y))
                pygame.time.delay(1)
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                x +=1                                              
                screen.fill((FILL)) 
                screen.blit(track, (0, 0))       
                screen.blit(car,(x,y))
                pygame.time.delay(1)             
    pygame.display.update()       
    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: pygame.transform.rotate()

Answer (score 0):

[как один из возможных вариантов](https://coderoad.ru/4183208/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-Pygame)